# Is there any way to find blocks of same patterns in text or string?

Tags: python, pattern-matching

**Example**

**I have a text or string like:**
"Student 1
Student Name - abcd xyz
abcd is smart kid.
Roll No - 1
Remark - Need little focus on study.
Student 2
Student Name - pqr def 
pqr is intelligent kid.
Roll No - 3"

So here I am trying to get 2 blocks like:
**Block 1** :
Student 1
Student Name - abcd xyz
abcd is smart kid.
Roll No - 1

**Block 2** :
Student 2
Student Name - pqr def 
pqr is intelligent kid.
Roll No - 3

Comment: Are the blocks always the same number of lines? You can try minimize string similarity metrics such as Levenshtein distance or cosine similarity by changing block size. The block size that minimizes the metric would give you the desired split.

Answer (score 0):

This might work using regex split using `Roll No` as a match

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """Student 1
Student Name - abcd xyz
abcd is smart kid.
Roll No - 1
Remark - Need little focus on study.
Student 2
Student Name - pqr def
pqr is intelligent kid.
Roll No - 3"""

data = re.split("(Roll No \- \d+)", s)
for i in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
('Student 1\nStudent Name - abcd xyz\nabcd is smart kid.\n', 'Roll No - 1')
('\nRemark - Need little focus on study.\nStudent 2\nStudent Name - pqr def\npqr is intelligent kid.\n', 'Roll No - 3')
```